# How to finish AsyncTask with Intent while passing extra data?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions

I am having a problem with Android programming in Kotlin.

I have a near bog-standard `LoginActivity` from Android Studio. An inner class is provided with an `AsyncTask` to complete the login action in a separate thread to prevent the application from becoming unresponsive.

My problem is that when I write my login code in the `AsyncTask` and provide the resulting output to the `putExtra()` function of an `Intent`, the resulting `Intent` does not have *any* information inside itself. Instead, I always get a `NullPointerException` when trying to access the data from the new activity.

My code is as follows:

```
// Inner AsyncTask class from LoginActivity
inner class UserLoginAsync constructor(var mSid: String, var mUsername: String, var mPassword: String): AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {
    var data: String? = ""
    override fun doInBackground(vararg params: Void?): String {
        // Run request with OkHttp.
    }
    override fun onPostExecute(result: String) {
        showProgress(false)
        if(data != "") {
            val intent: Intent = Intent(this@LoginActivity, HomeActivity::class.java).apply {
                putExtra("data", data)
            }
            startActivity(intent)
            finish()
        } else {
            password.error = getString(R.string.error_incorrect_password)
            password.requestFocus()
        }
    }
}
```

If I rewrite the code without `AsyncTask,` it works just fine but hangs the UI thread while it runs and does not provide the user with graphical feedback during the process of making the request.

How would I write the `Intent` so that it provides the new activity with the needed data?

**Edit** As requested, here is the code from `HomeActivity`:

```
class HomeActivity : AppCompatActivity(), NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
    val keyname: String = "data"
    val data: JSONObject = JSONObject(intent.getStringExtra(keyname))
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home)
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
        userName.text = data.getJSONObject("student").getString("name")
        userEmail.text = data.getJSONObject("student").getString("email")
        fab.setOnClickListener { view ->
            Snackbar.make(view, "You tapped the fab! Good job!", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                .setAction("Action", null).show()
        }

        val toggle = ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer_layout, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close)
        drawer_layout.addDrawerListener(toggle)
        toggle.syncState()
        nav_view.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this)
    }
}
```

Comment: "the resulting `Intent` does not have any information inside itself" -- have you examined the `intent` before the `startActivity()` call? Does it have the extra? Also, note that `Intent` uses the builder pattern, so you should be able to skip the `apply` lambda and use `val intent = Intent(this@LoginActivity, HomeActivity::class.java).putExtra("data", data)`.

Comment: Hello! I have examined the Intent before the `startActivity()` call. It does have the information intended to be passed. That, and thanks for the tip on the apply lambda.

Comment: OK, so if the `Intent` is correct going into `startActivity()`, perhaps your problem is in how you are trying to use the `Intent` in `HomeActivity`.

Comment: Would you like my code from `HomeActivity`? I will happily post it. In fact, it's also quite bog-standard, as I have not started customizing it yet since this bug has been raddling my brain.

Comment: "Would you like my code from HomeActivity?" -- it's possible we'll see something there that will help, so if it's not too much trouble, editing your question and posting that code would be cool.

Comment: Okay, all done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 val data: JSONObject = JSONObject(intent.getStringExtra(keyname))
```

`intent` (a.k.a., `getIntent()` in Java) will crash here. You cannot use that from a field initializer, because the `Activity` has not been initialized properly yet. You have to wait until `onCreate()`, and ideally after the `super.onCreate()` call.

You might try `lateinit var data: JSONObject`, and doing the initialization in `onCreate()` after the `super.onCreate()` call.

Comment: Thank you! This solved the problem correctly and succinctly.

Comment: I will have to retract my correct answer marking, it worked yesterday, but it for some reason is not working today. The string is now null, again, trying both the `lateinit` and the `super.onCreate()` strategies. It seems to fail silently between these two activities, the problem being that I am having trouble tracing it.

Comment: I have solved my problem. I am using a cache file now and parsing it in the new activity; while this may work for me, I would still encourage others to try this solution first. Therefore, I have re-marked this as the solution.